# Recommended way to remove WP REST API returned data for custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, json, rest-api

I have been searching for the proper way to modify the returned responses for a custom post type. I have found a way to do it but the official documentation discourages this method.

I personally don't think it would matter since it's a custom post type that only the part of the application that I built interacts with it but I'd still like to do it the proper way.

Wordpress suggests that a custom context is created before removing the any data from the response, but I can't find any documentation that shows how to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction to doing this.

I know they strongly discourage this practice but I am getting over 20 fields which includes arrays and objects when I only need like 5/6 of these. I'm sure it will make a big difference in the speed and responsiveness of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the [docs state](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/):

> Note that the API cannot prevent you from changing responses, but the code is structured to strongly discourage this. Internally, **field registration is powered by filters**, and **these can be used if you absolutely have no other choice.**

there ***IS*** another choice for most cases, namely: [custom endpoints/routes](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/).

You can even assign a rest controller class to the CPT. So you can extend [WP_Rest_Posts_Controller](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/) and set [custom endpoints, their routes](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/), parameters, and the corresponding callbacks to respond with whatever you need.

The steps involved are:

1. set `rest_controller_class` for custom post type (CPT)
2. `Extend WP_REST_Controller` or `WP_REST_Posts_Controller`
3. Register routes and define methods
4. Possibly control response format with Schema

NOTE: `WP_REST_Posts_Controller` itself is extending [`WP_REST_Controller`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_controller/).

### Setting `rest_controller_class` argument for CPT:

1) In `$args` array while registering:

```
    $labels = array( ... );
    $args = array(
                'labels'                => $labels,
                ...
                ...
                'show_in_rest'          => true,
                'rest_base'             => 'my_rest_base',
              //'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',
                'rest_controller_class' => 'My_CPT_Controller_Class'
              );
    register_post_type( 'my-post-type', $args );
```

2) To add after CPT is registered, use the filter hook: [`register_post_type_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_args/)

```
function add_rest_stuff( $args, $post_type ) {
    $custom_post_type = 'my-post-type';

    if ( $post_type !== $custom_post_type ) {
     return $args;
    }

    $args['show_in_rest'] = true;
    $args['rest_base'] = 'my_rest_base';
    $args['rest_controller_class'] = 'My_CPT_Controller_Class';

    return $args;
}
add_filter('register_post_type_args', 'make_it_public' );
```

### Extending `WP_REST_Controller` for Custom endpoint(s)/route(s):

A quick partial example as a starting point (from a [previous answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/270165/118366))

```
    class My_CPT_Controller_Class extends WP_REST_Controller {
            public function __construct() {
                add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'register_routes' ) );
            }//end __construct

            public function register_routes() {
                $version = '1';
                $namespace = 'my-fancy-namespace/v' . $version; 
                $base = 'my-route-base';

    // so, site.com/wp-json/my-fancy-namespace/v1/my-route-base/

                register_rest_route( $namespace, '/'. $base, array(
                    array(
                        'methods'  => 'GET',
                        'callback' => array( $this, 'my_get_callback' ),
                        'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'key_permissions_check' ),
                        ),
                    array(
                        'methods'  => 'POST',
                        'callback' => array( $this, 'my_post_callback' ),
                        'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'key_permissions_check' ),
                        ),)
                );

                $base2 = 'my-second-base';
    // so, site.com/wp-json/my-fancy-namespace/v1/my-second-base/

                register_rest_route( $namespace, '/'. $base2, array(
                    array(
                        'methods'  => 'GET',
                        'callback' => array( $this, 'my_get_callback_two' ),
                        'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'key_permissions_check' ),
                        ),
                    array(
                        'methods'  => 'POST',
                        'callback' => array( $this, 'my_post_callback_two' ),
                        'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'key_permissions_check' ),
                        ),)
                );

        }//register_routes

       public function key_permissions_check() {
          //do permissions check stuff
       }

       public function my_get_callback( WP_REST_Request $request ) {

            //do stuff with $request 
           //see the methods mentioned below
        }//end 
    }//end class
```

The [WP_Rest_Request class provides several methods](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/) for dealing with `$request`.

### Schema

Look into [Schema](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/schema/#resource-schema) as well for building the responses.

I've added the `prefix_get_comment()` example from the bottom of that page since it is a straightforward example:

```
function prefix_register_my_comment_route() {
    register_rest_route( 'my-namespace/v1', '/comments', array(
        // Notice how we are registering multiple endpoints the 'schema' equates to an OPTIONS request.
        array(
            'methods'  => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'prefix_get_comment_sample',
        ),
        // Register our schema callback.
        'schema' => 'prefix_get_comment_schema',
    ) );
}
/**
 * Get our sample schema for comments.
 */
function prefix_get_comment_schema() {
    $schema = array(
        // This tells the spec of JSON Schema we are using which is draft 4.
        '$schema'              => 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
        // The title property marks the identity of the resource.
        'title'                => 'comment',
        'type'                 => 'object',
        // In JSON Schema you can specify object properties in the properties attribute.
        'properties'           => array(
            'id' => array(
                'description'  => esc_html__( 'Unique identifier for the object.', 'my-textdomain' ),
                'type'         => 'integer',
                'context'      => array( 'view', 'edit', 'embed' ),
                'readonly'     => true,
            ),
            'author' => array(
                'description'  => esc_html__( 'The id of the user object, if author was a user.', 'my-textdomain' ),
                'type'         => 'integer',
            ),
            'content' => array(
                'description'  => esc_html__( 'The content for the object.', 'my-textdomain' ),
                'type'         => 'string',
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $schema;
}
```