# Get custom data from the user REST API endpoint

Tags: rest-api

If I request a user from the `user` REST API endpoint described here : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#retrieve-a-user

I don't see any of the custom data, is there a way to include it in the response?

Comment: What do you mean by custom data?

Comment: Do you mean user_meta values? You'll need to register them with the REST API to get the endpoint to return them. I can't remember the name of the call or filter off the top of my head sorry.

Comment: thanks @Rup it's probably it, I found that: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270154/getting-user-meta-data-from-wp-rest-api