# How to customize user rest api?

Tags: users, rest-api

I am building a website VueJS and wordpress rest api. I am now working on author rest api. When i send get users :

```
get http://www.mywebsite.org/wp-json/wp/v2/users
```

I have the following result :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Christian DOE",
        "url": "",
        "description": "Whats'up men ",
        "link": "http://www.mywebsite.org/author/davy-kialagmail-com/",
        "slug": "christian,
        "avatar_urls": {
            "24": "http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/7cd93799879d879e4f3a9d6f35e78fd3?s=24&d=mm&r=g",
            "48": "http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/7cd93799879d879e4f3a9d6f35e78fd3?s=48&d=mm&r=g",
            "96": "http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/7cd93799879d879e4f3a9d6f35e78fd3?s=96&d=mm&r=g"
        },
        "meta": [],
        "acf": [],
        "_links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "http://www.mywebsite.org/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
                }
            ],
            "collection": [
                {
                    "href": "http://www.mywebsite.org/wp-json/wp/v2/users"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Jean Charles",
        "url": "",
        "description": "It's me ",
        "link": "http://www.mywebsite.org/author/dkiala/",
        "slug": "charles",
        "avatar_urls": {
            "24": "http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/aa00691cc2b1cc4d3ad4f6be3a190877?s=24&d=mm&r=g",
            "48": "http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/aa00691cc2b1cc4d3ad4f6be3a190877?s=48&d=mm&r=g",
            "96": "http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/aa00691cc2b1cc4d3ad4f6be3a190877?s=96&d=mm&r=g"
        },
        "meta": [],
        "acf": [],
        "_links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "http://www.mywebsite.org/wp-json/wp/v2/users/3"
                }
            ],
            "collection": [
                {
                    "href": "http://www.mywebsite.org/wp-json/wp/v2/users"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "utilisateurtest",
        "url": "",
        "description": "Me aand me ",
        "link": "http://www.mywebsite.org/author/utilisateurtest/",
        "slug": "utilisateurtest",
        "avatar_urls": {
            "24": "http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/8eef2832389bb97a73c25d9ebe8583bd?s=24&d=mm&r=g",
            "48": "http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/8eef2832389bb97a73c25d9ebe8583bd?s=48&d=mm&r=g",
            "96": "http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/8eef2832389bb97a73c25d9ebe8583bd?s=96&d=mm&r=g"
        },
        "meta": [],
        "acf": [],
        "_links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "http://www.mywebsite.org/wp-json/wp/v2/users/2"
                }
            ],
            "collection": [
                {
                    "href": "http://www.mywebsite.org/wp-json/wp/v2/users"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

My aim is to customize users rest api : i would like to have a list of user social link users.

Is there a plugin i can use to :
1. to set the user social link ?
2. To get those links exposed by rest api ?

I've tried the following solution :

1.I upload a wordpress plugin to add some data. [It's Simple Author plugin](https://github.com/GreenTreeLabs/simple-author-box) 
I am able to add some additional data to user ( social link list )
2. I create a plugin to add this meta data be filled when i retrieved users from rest api.
Here my plugin code :

```
 add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'adding_user_meta_rest' );

    function adding_user_meta_rest() {
       register_rest_field( 'user',
                            'collapsed_widgets',
                             array(
                               'get_callback'      => 'user_meta_callback',
                               'update_callback'   => null,
                               'schema'            => null,
                                )
                          );
    }


    function user_meta_callback( $user, $field_name, $request) {
       return get_user_meta( $user[ 'id' ], $field_name, true );
    }
```

I've tried a rest api get users request but i did not have the meta data listed in my response.

If you have an idea, i would like to know.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you build your own plugin so that it adds the social media profiles, you should be able to just enable those extra fields to be included in the REST API - I've not done this myself but have done it with CPTs.

Comment: Thanks @TonyDjukic for your answer. Do you have a tutorial i can follow to do it with CPTs ?

Comment: Here's two examples that I've looked at before that, I think, are within range of what you're asking:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270154/getting-user-meta-data-from-wp-rest-api