# What is the meta field in the response of the user REST API?

Tags: rest-api

I use this command to send to the API:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://www.domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/14?context=view' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'authorization: Basic SmVmZnJleTpCdW1ibGViZWUwNjA0'
```

and I get this response:

```
{
  "id": 14,
  "name": "User",
  "url": "",
  "description": "",
  "link": "https://www.domain.com/author/User/",
  "slug": "User",
  "avatar_urls": {
    "24": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/",
    "48": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/",
    "96": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/"
  },
  "meta": [],
  "_links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/14"
      }
    ],
    "collection": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what the "Meta":[] field is? If it is the user's Metadata then how do I use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into register_rest_field() to register meta with the rest api.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'adding_user_meta_rest' );

function adding_user_meta_rest() {
   register_rest_field( 'user',
                        'collapsed_widgets',
                         array(
                           'get_callback'      => 'user_meta_callback',
                           'update_callback'   => null,
                           'schema'            => null,
                            )
                      );
}
```

And then put your get_user_meta bit in the callback.

```
   function user_meta_callback( $user, $field_name, $request) {
       return get_user_meta( $user[ 'id' ], $field_name, true );
   }
```

The WP_REST_Meta_Fields class may provide more useful insight as well.

Answer copy from - [Getting user meta data from WP REST API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270154/getting-user-meta-data-from-wp-rest-api?rq=1)

Comment: have you looked at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/ ? The method in your question is old, there are newer better ways to register meta that work better with the block editor too