# Custom uploader - Upload files and save link into database

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, uploads

I'm working on a file manager plugin. I need to store the saved files in custom folders and save the link into database to be able to get all the files and folders structure inside my vue front-end. Is there any function or hook I can use to do this?

Comment: If you just want to save some data against the user then you save it in user meta over te existing REST API if you register a new meta field: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270154/getting-user-meta-data-from-wp-rest-api

Comment: However it sounds to me like you'll need a complete new REST API for your file management.

Comment: @Rup I'm writing my custom endpoints, I'm looking for a way to be able to see all the uploaded files also from media library of wordpress or can have the ability to use the default media uploader instead of writing a custom one